# ZingChart display multiples of a value in x-axis

Tags: javascript, charts, zingchart

Suppose I have in x-axis with values from 0 to 2049. My values are series. What I would have to do to display only 0,500,1000,1500,2000, i.e. every other 500 tick mark, I haven't found an example yet. I tried max-labels but because my values are more than 2000, i don't get multiples of 500.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You have `scale-x`, did you mean `scale-y`?

If you are talking about `scale-y` you can set the `minValue`, `maxValue` and `step` between the scales. You can set those all individually or you can set them like `values: 'minValue:maxValue:step'`. `itemsOverlap` just forces all items to render, even if their height or width overlaps an item above or below it.

```js
var myConfig = {
  type: 'bar', 
  scaleY: {
    values: '0:2000:500',
    maxItems: 5,
    itemsOverlap: true,
  },
 series: [
  {
   values: [2235,4442,3367,1389,2325,3334,4567,2385]
  }
 ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id: 'myChart', 
 data: myConfig, 
 height: '100%', 
 width: '100%' 
});
```

```css
html, body {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#myChart {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 min-height:150px;
}
.zc-ref {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="myChart"><a class="zc-ref" href="https://www.zingchart.com">Powered by ZingChart</a></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

If this is answer is not what you are looking for, please notify.

Scales documentation:

https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/chart-elements/configure-chart-scales/

https://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/json-configuration/graphset/scale-x/

Comment: it's actually the x-axis that should be multples of 500. My values series, and they're more 2000,